# PHP functions and variables

Tags: php

index.php:

```
<?php
    require("lib.php");

    echo getName();
?>
```

lib.php:

```
<?php
    $name = "Matej";

    function getName() {
        return $name;
    }
?>
```

Code doesnt work, i think its becouse PHP cant get variable form outsite of function. how to fix it?

Comment: 1) If you write a question with "Code doesnt work", explain *what* doesn't work, what you expect and what you get right now 2) If something doesn't work, add error reporting to the top of each file: `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for errors 3) *"i think its becouse PHP cant get variable form outsite of function"* <- If you already have guess what the problem could be, try to approve / disapprove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can lean about variable scope [here](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php). If you want using global variables, then use `global` keyword.

```
function getName() {
    global $name;
    return $name;
}
```

But... well, global is evil. In your case, a function like this is useless. Simply use `$name`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get value of $name outside function, you could call the function sending the value to it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the variable does not have the global keyword!

```
$name = 'hello';
function name() {
     return global $name;
}
```